# На чём потренироваться писать искусственные интеллекты для игр?

Tags: javascript, java, разработка-игр, искусственный-интеллект

Лично мне приходят два варианта:

Первый.

Сайты вроде http://russianaicup.ru/ подходят для этого идеально. Сам этот сайт доступен только в конкурсном формате - сейчас отправлять ничего нельзя. Других подобных сайтов не видел - буду рад, если подскажете.

Второй.

Взять какую-нибудь готовую игру и изменить AI персонажей в нём. Искал на GitHub'е, но ничего хорошего мне пока не попалось. В основном все игры либо слишком сложные (месяц будешь разбираться в механике), либо недоделанные. Очень желательно, чтобы игрушка была написана на *Java* или *JS*. Буду рад, если подскажете подходящую.

Конечно, можно и свой мир "запилить", и в нём AI гонять, но это слишком долго и нудно.

Comment: Могу предложить "воссоздание ИИ" на Java. Если интересует, какие-нибудь координаты для связи. Проект на Гитхабе.

Comment: @ArchDemon напишите мне тогда на ящик (то же имя, что и здесь)@gmail.com

Comment: Раз: http://fightcodegame.com/, два: http://habrahabr.ru/company/2gis/blog/251283/

Comment: Не понимаю смысл всех этих редактирований, но фраза "месяц будешь разбираться в механике" точно нужна

Comment: Не знаю как мне не пришло это в голову раньше, но гуглинг фразы "ai competition" даёт много интересного

Answer (score -2):

Не очень понимаю, зачем тебе вообще с ИИ тренироваться. Само по себе написание ИИ не прикрепленной к конкретной данной задачи - это телега впереди лошади (мое мнение). Куда правильнее, я считаю, работать над конкретным продуктом и уже к нему, как составляющие, писать уже конкретный(е) ИИ под конкретные задачи. Вот как ты и сказал - свой мир "запилить": сделай свою игру и реализуй там ИИ - это будет куда правильнее, я считаю. А просто навыки по написанию ИИ тебе мало чего дадут: для тривиальных задач уже все изъезженно-переезженно, а для нетривиальных задач тебе все равно придется сидеть и ломать голову над алгоритмами в не зависимости от опыта на "тривиалках". В таком случае я бы тебе советовал лучше вообще углубляться в корень - в алгоритмы как таковые (в не зависимости ИИ/не ИИ) - в конце концов, любой игровой ИИ это не более чем набор алгритмов для решения различных задач + генератор случайных чисел для илюзии праавдоподобности=)